# Parse cloud code relations query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, pfuser

I'm trying to query whether a PFUser exists in another PFUser's 'blockedUsers' relation column before sending a push notification:

I have written this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var recipientBlockList = toUser.relation("blockedUsers");
var blockListQuery = Parse.Query(recipientBlockList);
blockListQuery.contains(fromUser);
blockListQuery.find({
    success: function(users) {

    },
    error: function() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For relation object queries, you should use `yourRelation.query()`:

```
var blockListQuery = recipientBlockList.query();
```